# How to convert from urllib to scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, urllib

I am webscraping an output of url amazon links, each of these links contains the price of a given book. So, the idea is to get the link and the price of the book of that link.

I have created code using `urllib`. However, after running this code, I got an HTTP response `status code 308` because I want to scrape 230 links. I did a search and find out that `urllib` doesn't yet support 308 codes, and I think that Scrapy would.

Here is my `urllib` code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import ast
from time import sleep

url= "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/full-overview.json?api- 
key=mykey "

data = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(data)

best_sellers_history = []
for index in range(0,len(data['results']['lists'])):
   for book in range(0,len(data['results']['lists'][index]['books'])):
      amazon_product_url = (data['results']['lists'][index]['books'][book] 
   ['amazon_product_url'])
    pprint((amazon_product_url)
      req = Request(amazon_product_url, headers=ast.literal_eval("{'User- 
    Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}"))
      page = urlopen(req)
      soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
      price = soup.find('span',{'class':'a-size-base a-color-price a-color-price'})
      if price:
         price = price.get_text(strip=True).replace('$', '')
      else:
         price = "None"
      print(price)
      sleep(2)
```

I tried and failed to convert this into scrapy. Could anyone help me to convert this into scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is converting to `Scrapy` for gettering Amazon books list from NY Times API server.

Steps

```
$scrapy startproject amazon
$cd amazon
$scrapy genspider ny-times https://www.nytimes.com/
```

It will created files

```
D:\temp\amazon>tree /F
Folder PATH listing for volume DATA
Volume serial number is 16D6-338C
D:.
│   scrapy.cfg
│
└───amazon
    │   items.py
    │   middlewares.py
    │   pipelines.py
    │   settings.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───spiders
    │   │   ny_times.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   └───__pycache__
    │           __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │
    └───__pycache__
            settings.cpython-310.pyc
            __init__.cpython-310.pyc
```

Among this files we will touch only two files (`items.py` and `ny_times.py`)

Overwrite two files with this code

#### `ny_times.py`

```py
import scrapy
import json
from amazon.items import AmazonItem


class NyTimesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ny-times'

    start_urls = ['https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/full-overview.json?api-key=******** your API-KEY **********']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url, 
                callback = self.url_parse
            )

    def url_parse(self, response):
        books = []
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.text)
        for lists in jsonresponse['results']['lists']:
            for book in lists['books']:
                books.append({
                    'amazon_product_url' : book['amazon_product_url']
                })
        
        for book in books:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                book['amazon_product_url'], 
                callback = self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//span[@id='productTitle']//text()").get().strip()
        price = response.xpath("//span[@class='a-size-base a-color-price a-color-price']//text()").get().strip()
        loader = AmazonItem()  # Here you create a new item each iteration
        loader['title'] = title
        loader['url'] = response.request.url
        loader['price'] = price
        yield loader
```

#### `items.py`

```
import scrapy

class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

#### Run it with save into `result.json`

if you success those step, you can see this log in terminal.

```json
$scrapy crawl ny-times -O result.json
...
[
{"title": "Demon Copperhead: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Demon-Copperhead-Novel-Barbara-Kingsolver/dp/0063251922", "price": "$19.82"},
{"title": "Friends, Lovers, and the Big Terrible Thing: A Memoir", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Friends-Lovers-Big-Terrible-Thing/dp/1250866448", "price": "$14.00"},
{"title": "Triple Cross: The Greatest Alex Cross Thriller Since Kiss the Girls (An Alex Cross Thriller, 28)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Triple-Cross-Alex-Thriller-28/dp/0316499188", "price": "$14.00"},
{"title": "The Light We Carry: Overcoming in Uncertain Times", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/the-light-we-carry/dp/0593237463", "price": "$16.89"},
{"title": "I'm Glad My Mom Died", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Im-Glad-My-Mom-Died/dp/1982185821", "price": "$17.28"},
{"title": "The Seven Husbands of Evelyn Hugo: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Seven-Husbands-Evelyn-Hugo-Novel/dp/1501161938", "price": "$9.42"},
{"title": "Where the Crawdads Sing", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Where-Crawdads-Sing-Delia-Owens/dp/0735219095", "price": "$14.63"},
{"title": "The Silent Patient", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Silent-Patient-Alex-Michaelides/dp/1250301696", "price": "$12.99"},
{"title": "Fairy Tale", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Fairy-Tale-Stephen-King/dp/1668002175", "price": "$16.25"},
{"title": "November 9: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/November-9-Novel-Colleen-Hoover-ebook/dp/B00UDCI1S8", "price": "$10.99"},
{"title": "The Boys from Biloxi: A Legal Thriller", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Boys-Biloxi-Legal-Thriller/dp/0385548923", "price": "$14.00"},
{"title": "Mad Honey: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Mad-Honey-Novel-Jodi-Picoult/dp/1984818384", "price": "$15.67"},
{"title": "Dreamland: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Dreamland-Novel-Nicholas-Sparks/dp/059344955X", "price": "$14.00"},
{"title": "Verity", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Verity-Colleen-Hoover/dp/1791392792", "price": "$17.00"},
{"title": "Ugly Love: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Ugly-Love-Novel-Colleen-Hoover-ebook/dp/B00HB62MC0", "price": "$10.99"},
{"title": "Six of Crows (Six of Crows, 1)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Six-Crows-Leigh-Bardugo/dp/1627792120", "price": "$11.49"},
{"title": "Legendborn (The Legendborn Cycle)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Legendborn-Tracy-Deonn/dp/1534441603", "price": "$13.26"},
{"title": "She's Gone", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Shes-Gone-David-Bell/dp/1728254205", "price": "$9.89"},
{"title": "Better Than the Movies", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Better-Than-Movies-Lynn-Painter/dp/1534467637", "price": "$10.38"},
{"title": "Demon Slayer: Kimetsu no Yaiba―The Flower of Happiness (Demon Slayer: Kimetsu no Yaiba Novels)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Demon-Slayer-Kimetsu-Yaiba_The-Happiness/dp/1974732525", "price": "$8.68"},
{"title": "They Both Die at the End", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/They-Both-Die-at-End/dp/0062457799", "price": "$13.99"},
{"title": "All the Bright Places", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/All-Bright-Places-Jennifer-Niven/dp/0385755880", "price": "$15.76"},
{"title": "The Book Thief", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Book-Thief-Markus-Zusak/dp/0375842209", "price": "$6.99"},
{"title": "We Were Liars", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/We-Were-Liars-Lockhart-ebook/dp/B00FPOSDGY", "price": "$8.99"},
{"title": "Amari and the Night Brothers (Supernatural Investigations, 1)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Amari-Night-Brothers-Supernatural-Investigations/dp/0062975161", "price": "$14.99"},
{"title": "The One and Only Bob (One and Only Ivan)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/One-Only-Bob-Ivan/dp/0062991310", "price": "$11.79"},
{"title": "Restart", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Restart-Gordon-Korman/dp/1338053809", "price": "$6.49"},
{"title": "A Wolf Called Wander", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Wolf-Called-Wander-Rosanne-Parry/dp/0062895931", "price": "$10.14"},
{"title": "Map of Flames (The Forgotten Five, Book 1)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Map-Flames-Forgotten-Five-Book/dp/0593325400", "price": "$10.59"},
{"title": "Pax", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Pax-Sara-Pennypacker/dp/0062377019", "price": "$13.93"},
{"title": "The Wild Robot (The Wild Robot, 1)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Wild-Robot-Peter-Brown/dp/0316381993", "price": "$7.60"},
{"title": "A Christmas Promise: A Will and a Way and Home for Christmas: A 2-in-1 Collection", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Christmas-Promise-2-1-Collection/dp/1250847257", "price": "$7.83"},
{"title": "Wish", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Wish-Barbara-OConnor/dp/1250144051", "price": "$4.17"},
{"title": "A Long Walk to Water: Based on a True Story", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Long-Walk-Water-Based-Story/dp/0547577311", "price": "$7.64"},
{"title": "Dear Santa: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Dear-Santa-Novel-Debbie-Macomber/dp/1984818813", "price": "$12.51"},
{"title": "The One and Only Ivan", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/One-Only-Ivan-Katherine-Applegate/dp/0061992275", "price": "$6.96"},
{"title": "Snowflakes and Starlight: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Snowflakes-Starlight-Novel-Debbie-Macomber/dp/0778386902", "price": "$7.48"},
{"title": "Blind Tiger", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Blind-Tiger-Sandra-Brown/dp/1538751968", "price": "$9.48"},
{"title": "False Witness: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/False-Witness-Novel-Karin-Slaughter/dp/0062858092", "price": "$15.00"},
{"title": "Kingdom of Bones: A Thriller (Sigma Force Novels, 22)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Kingdom-Bones-Thriller-Sigma-Novels/dp/0062892983", "price": "$12.89"},
{"title": "The Santa Suit: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Santa-Suit-Mary-Kay-Andrews/dp/1250279313", "price": "$15.99"},
{"title": "Flying Angels: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Flying-Angels-Novel-Danielle-Steel/dp/1984821555", "price": "$13.00"},
{"title": "Wyoming Homecoming: A Novel (Wyoming Men, 11)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Wyoming-Homecoming-Men-11/dp/1335620958", "price": "$7.48"},
{"title": "Tom Clancy Chain of Command (A Jack Ryan Novel)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Clancy-Chain-Command-Jack-Novel/dp/0593188160", "price": "$15.17"},
{"title": "Chainsaw Man, Vol. 4 (4)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Chainsaw-Man-Vol-4/dp/1974717275", "price": "$9.99"},
{"title": "The Paris Detective", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Paris-Detective-James-Patterson/dp/1538718847", "price": "$7.48"},
{"title": "The Dark Hours (A Renée Ballard and Harry Bosch Novel, 4)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Hours-Ren%C3%A9e-Ballard-Harry-Bosch/dp/0316485640", "price": "$14.29"},
{"title": "Invisible: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Invisible-Novel-Danielle-Steel/dp/198482158X", "price": "$13.40"},
{"title": "Cat Kid Comic Club: Perspectives: A Graphic Novel (Cat Kid Comic Club #2): From the Creator of Dog Man", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Cat-Kid-Comic-Club-Perspectives/dp/1338784854", "price": "$8.68"},
{"title": "The Bad Guys in Open Wide and Say Arrrgh! (The Bad Guys #15)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Bad-Guys-Open-Wide-Arrrgh/dp/1338813188", "price": "$5.24"},
{"title": "The Judge's List: A Novel (The Whistler)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Judges-List-Novel-John-Grisham/dp/0385546025", "price": "$13.55"},
{"title": "Dog Man: For Whom the Ball Rolls: From the Creator of Captain Underpants (Dog Man #7)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Dog-Man-Creator-Captain-Underpants/dp/1338236598", "price": "$6.78"},
{"title": "Shuna's Journey", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Shunas-Journey-Hayao-Miyazaki/dp/1250846528", "price": "$19.59"},
{"title": "Chainsaw Man, Vol. 3 (3)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Chainsaw-Man-Vol-3/dp/1974709957", "price": "$9.98"},
{"title": "Chainsaw Man, Vol. 2 (2)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Chainsaw-Man-Vol-2/dp/1974709949", "price": "$9.73"},
{"title": "Number One Is Walking: My Life in the Movies and Other Diversions", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Number-One-Walking-Movies-Diversions/dp/1250815290", "price": "$15.00"},
{"title": "Chainsaw Man, Vol. 1 (1)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Chainsaw-Man-Vol-1/dp/1974709930", "price": "$7.68"},
{"title": "Jessi's Secret Language: A Graphic Novel (The Baby-sitters Club #12) (The Baby-Sitters Club Graphix)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Jessis-Secret-Language-Baby-sitters-Graphic/dp/1338616072", "price": "$10.99"},
{"title": "Dog Man: Grime and Punishment: A Graphic Novel (Dog Man #9): From the Creator of Captain Underpants (9)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Dog-Man-Punishment-Creator-Underpants/dp/1338535625", "price": "$6.48"},
{"title": "Dog Man: Mothering Heights: A Graphic Novel (Dog Man #10): From the Creator of Captain Underpants (10)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Dog-Man-Mothering-Heights-Underpants/dp/1338680455", "price": "$6.78"},
{"title": "The Bad Guys in the Others?! (The Bad Guys #16)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Bad-Guys-16-Aaron-Blabey/dp/1338820532", "price": "$5.78"},
{"title": "Cat Kid Comic Club: On Purpose: A Graphic Novel (Cat Kid Comic Club #3): From the Creator of Dog Man", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Cat-Kid-Comic-Club-Purpose/dp/1338801945", "price": "$8.21"},
{"title": "Cat Kid Comic Club: Collaborations: A Graphic Novel (Cat Kid Comic Club #4): From the Creator of Dog Man", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Cat-Kid-Comic-Club-Collaborations/dp/1338846620", "price": "$7.49"},
{"title": "The Book of Boundaries: Set the Limits That Will Set You Free", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Book-Boundaries-Limits-That-Will/dp/0593448707", "price": "$21.69"},
{"title": "Power Failure: The Rise and Fall of an American Icon", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Power-Failure-Rise-Fall-American/dp/0593084160", "price": "$31.94"},
{"title": "Like a Rolling Stone: A Memoir", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Like-Rolling-Stone-Jann-Wenner/dp/0316415197", "price": "$17.50"},
{"title": "Chip War: The Fight for the World's Most Critical Technology", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Chip-War-Worlds-Critical-Technology/dp/1982172002", "price": "$24.99"},
{"title": "Empire of Pain: The Secret History of the Sackler Dynasty", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Empire-Pain-History-Sackler-Dynasty/dp/0385545681", "price": "$18.00"},
{"title": "What Happened to You : Conversations on Trauma, Resilience, and Healing", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/What-Happened-You-Understanding-Resilience/dp/1250223180", "price": "$14.49"},
{"title": "Grit: The Power of Passion and Perseverance", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Grit-Passion-Perseverance-Angela-Duckworth-ebook/dp/B010MH9V3W", "price": "$14.99"},
{"title": "Dare to Lead: Brave Work. Tough Conversations. Whole Hearts.", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Dare-Lead-Brave-Conversations-Hearts/dp/0399592520", "price": "$14.63"},
{"title": "Finding Me: A Memoir", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Finding-Me-Memoir-Viola-Davis/dp/0063037327", "price": "$18.48"},
{"title": "The Myth of Normal: Trauma, Illness, and Healing in a Toxic Culture", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Myth-Normal-Illness-Healing-Culture/dp/0593083881", "price": "$24.99"},
{"title": "The Trump Tapes: Bob Woodward's Twenty Interviews with President Donald Trump", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Trump-Tapes-Woodwards-Interviews-President/dp/1797124722", "price": "$44.78"},
{"title": "The Choice: The Dragon Heart Legacy, Book 3 (The Dragon Heart Legacy, 3)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Choice-Dragon-Heart-Legacy-Book/dp/1250272726", "price": "$15.23"},
{"title": "Greenlights", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Greenlights-Matthew-McConaughey/dp/0593139135", "price": "$15.00"},
{"title": "Bloodmarked (2) (The Legendborn Cycle)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Bloodmarked-Legendborn-Cycle-Tracy-Deonn/dp/1534441638", "price": "$9.99"},
{"title": "The Lost Metal: A Mistborn Novel (The Mistborn Saga, 7)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Lost-Metal-Mistborn-Novel-Saga/dp/0765391198", "price": "$23.48"},
{"title": "I Was Born for This", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Was-Born-This-Alice-Oseman/dp/1338830937", "price": "$12.00"},
{"title": "Loveless", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Loveless-Alice-Oseman/dp/133875193X", "price": "$9.49"},
{"title": "Family of Liars: The Prequel to We Were Liars", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Family-Liars-Prequel-We-Were/dp/0593485858", "price": "$11.99"},
{"title": "Lightlark (The Lightlark Saga Book 1)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Lightlark-Book-1-Alex-Aster/dp/1419760866", "price": "$14.76"},
{"title": "A Thousand Heartbeats", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Thousand-Heartbeats-Kiera-Cass/dp/0062665782", "price": "$14.98"},
{"title": "The First to Die at the End", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/First-Die-at-End/dp/0063240807", "price": "$12.99"},
{"title": "Five Survive", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Five-Survive-Holly-Jackson/dp/0593374169", "price": "$14.39"},
{"title": "Long Live the Pumpkin Queen: Tim Burton's The Nightmare Before Christmas", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Long-Live-Pumpkin-Queen-Nightmare/dp/1368069606", "price": "$13.16"},
{"title": "Straight On Till Morning (A Twisted Tale): A Twisted Tale", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Straight-Till-Morning-Twisted-Tale/dp/1484781309", "price": "$15.99"},
{"title": "One of Us Is Lying", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/One-Us-Lying-Karen-McManus/dp/1524714682", "price": "$10.70"},
{"title": "The Final Gambit (The Inheritance Games, 3)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Final-Gambit-Inheritance-Games/dp/0316370959", "price": "$11.79"},
{"title": "As Good as Dead: The Finale to A Good Girl's Guide to Murder", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/As-Good-Dead-Finale-Murder/dp/0593379853", "price": "$12.72"},
{"title": "The Last Kids on Earth and the Nightmare King", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Last-Kids-Earth-Nightmare-King/dp/0425288714", "price": "$8.50"},
{"title": "We'll Always Have Summer (The Summer I Turned Pretty)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Well-Always-Summer-Turned-Pretty/dp/1416995587", "price": "$14.18"},
{"title": "The Brightest Night (Wings of Fire #5) (5)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Wings-Fire-Book-Five-Brightest/dp/0545349222", "price": "$16.99"},
{"title": "Pete the Cat's 12 Groovy Days of Christmas: A Christmas Holiday Book for Kids", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Pete-Cats-Groovy-Days-Christmas/dp/0062675273", "price": "$5.84"},
{"title": "Captain Underpants and the Revolting Revenge of the Radioactive Robo-Boxers (Captain Underpants #10) (10)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Captain-Underpants-Revolting-Radioactive-Robo-Boxers/dp/0545175364", "price": "$7.44"},
{"title": "The Titan's Curse (Percy Jackson and the Olympians, Book 3)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Titans-Curse-Percy-Jackson-Olympians/dp/1423101480", "price": "$7.99"},
{"title": "How to Catch a Unicorn", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/How-Catch-Unicorn-Adam-Wallace/dp/1492669733", "price": "$5.74"},
{"title": "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (5)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Order-Phoenix-Rowling/dp/0439358078", "price": "$6.78"},
{"title": "Little Blue Truck Makes a Friend: A Friendship Book for Kids", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Little-Blue-Truck-Makes-Friend/dp/0358722829", "price": "$16.33"},
{"title": "5 More Sleeps ‘til Christmas", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/5-More-Sleeps-til-Christmas/dp/1250266475", "price": "$15.00"},
{"title": "Diary of a Wimpy Kid: Hard Luck, Book 8", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Diary-Wimpy-Kid-Hard-Luck/dp/1419711326", "price": "$8.95"},
{"title": "The Pigeon Will Ride the Roller Coaster!", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Pigeon-Will-Ride-Roller-Coaster/dp/1454946865", "price": "$13.99"},
{"title": "How to Catch an Elf", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/How-Catch-Elf-Adam-Wallace/dp/1492646318", "price": "$4.94"},
{"title": "Construction Site on Christmas Night: (Christmas Book for Kids, Children's Book, Holiday Picture Book) (Goodnight, Goodnight Construction Site)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Construction-Christmas-Sherri-Duskey-Rinker/dp/1452139113", "price": "$8.49"},
{"title": "The Door of No Return", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Door-No-Return-Kwame-Alexander/dp/0316441864", "price": "$12.39"},
{"title": "Daughter of the Deep", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Daughter-Deep-Rick-Riordan/dp/1368077927", "price": "$9.99"},
{"title": "The Wonderful Things You Will Be", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Wonderful-Things-You-Will-Be/dp/0385376715", "price": "$8.55"},
{"title": "Odder", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Odder-Katherine-Applegate/dp/1250147425", "price": "$8.49"},
{"title": "Two Degrees", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Two-Degrees-Alan-Gratz/dp/1338735675", "price": "$15.99"},
{"title": "The Day the Crayons Quit", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Day-Crayons-Quit-Drew-Daywalt/dp/0399255370", "price": "$9.19"},
{"title": "Unstoppable Us, Volume 1: How Humans Took Over the World (Unstoppable Us, 1)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Unstoppable-Us-Humans-Took-World/dp/0593643461", "price": "$21.99"},
{"title": "Wonder", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Wonder-R-J-Palacio/dp/B0051ANPZQ", "price": "$10.99"},
{"title": "Dragons Love Tacos", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Dragons-Love-Tacos-Adam-Rubin/dp/0803736800", "price": "$9.92"},
{"title": "The Official Harry Potter Baking Book: 40+ Recipes Inspired by the Films", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Official-Harry-Potter-Baking-Book/dp/1338285262", "price": "$13.98"},
{"title": "The Christmas Pig", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Christmas-Pig-J-K-Rowling/dp/1338790234", "price": "$14.00"},
{"title": "Half Baked Harvest Every Day: Recipes for Balanced, Flexible, Feel-Good Meals: A Cookbook", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Half-Baked-Harvest-Every-Day/dp/0593232550", "price": "$18.49"},
{"title": "The Complete Cookbook for Young Chefs: 100+ Recipes that You'll Love to Cook and Eat", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Complete-Cookbook-Young-Chefs/dp/1492670022", "price": "$10.44"},
{"title": "Atlas of the Heart: Mapping Meaningful Connection and the Language of Human Experience", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Atlas-Heart-Meaningful-Connection-Experience/dp/0399592555", "price": "$17.78"},
{"title": "The Boy, the Mole, the Fox and the Horse", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Boy-Mole-Fox-Horse/dp/0062976583", "price": "$12.01"},
{"title": "The Stories We Tell: Every Piece of Your Story Matters", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Stories-We-Tell-Every-Matters/dp/1400333873", "price": "$16.97"},
{"title": "The Complete Baking Book for Young Chefs: 100+ Sweet and Savory Recipes that You'll Love to Bake, Share and Eat!", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Complete-Baking-Book-Young-Chefs/dp/1492677698", "price": "$14.89"},
{"title": "The Simply Happy Cookbook: 100-Plus Recipes to Take the Stress Out of Cooking (The Happy Cookbook Series)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Simply-Happy-Cookbook-100-Plus-Recipes/dp/0063209233", "price": "$18.80"},
{"title": "Faith Still Moves Mountains: Miraculous Stories of the Healing Power of Prayer", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Faith-Still-Moves-Mountains-Miraculous/dp/006322593X", "price": "$17.45"},
{"title": "Never Finished: Unshackle Your Mind and Win the War Within", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Never-Finished-Unshackle-Your-Within/dp/1544534078", "price": "$18.45"},
{"title": "The Subtle Art of Not Giving a F*ck: A Counterintuitive Approach to Living a Good Life", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Subtle-Art-Not-Giving-Counterintuitive/dp/0062457713", "price": "$13.99"},
{"title": "Atomic Habits: An Easy & Proven Way to Build Good Habits & Break Bad Ones", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Atomic-Habits-Proven-Build-Break/dp/0735211299", "price": "$11.98"},
{"title": "These Precious Days: Essays", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/These-Precious-Days-Ann-Patchett/dp/0063092786", "price": "$17.88"},
{"title": "Go-To Dinners: A Barefoot Contessa Cookbook", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Go-Dinners-Barefoot-Contessa-Cookbook/dp/1984822780", "price": "$15.19"},
{"title": "Killers of the Flower Moon: The Osage Murders and the Birth of the FBI", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Killers-Flower-Moon-Osage-Murders/dp/0385534248", "price": "$14.59"},
{"title": "The Spy and the Traitor: The Greatest Espionage Story of the Cold War", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Spy-Traitor-Greatest-Espionage-Story/dp/1101904194", "price": "$64.99"},
{"title": "The Bomber Mafia: A Dream, a Temptation, and the Longest Night of the Second World War", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Bomber-Mafia-Temptation-Longest-Second/dp/0316296619", "price": "$13.97"},
{"title": "Educated: A Memoir", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Educated-Memoir-Tara-Westover/dp/0399590501", "price": "$14.63"},
{"title": "Talking to Strangers: What We Should Know about the People We Don't Know", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Talking-Strangers-Should-about-People/dp/0316478520", "price": "$13.38"},
{"title": "The Splendid and the Vile: A Saga of Churchill, Family, and Defiance During the Blitz", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Splendid-Vile-Churchill-Family-Defiance/dp/0385348711", "price": "$14.90"},
{"title": "Devotion (Movie Tie-in): An Epic Story of Heroism, Friendship, and Sacrifice", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Devotion-Movie-Tie-Friendship-Sacrifice/dp/0593722337", "price": "$20.00"},
{"title": "The Greatest Beer Run Ever: A Memoir of Friendship, Loyalty, and War", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Greatest-Beer-Run-Ever-Friendship/dp/0062995464", "price": "$17.98"},
{"title": "All About Love: New Visions", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/All-About-Love-New-Visions/dp/0060959479", "price": "$12.84"},
{"title": "Maybe Now: A Novel (Maybe Someday)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Maybe-Now-Novel-Someday/dp/1668013347", "price": "$10.65"},
{"title": "Daisy Jones & The Six: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Daisy-Jones-Taylor-Jenkins-Reid/dp/1524798622", "price": "$22.99"},
{"title": "All Your Perfects: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/All-Your-Perfects-Colleen-Hoover-ebook/dp/B078MC547V", "price": "$10.99"},
{"title": "Things We Never Got Over", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Things-We-Never-Got-Over/dp/1728278872", "price": "$18.97"},
{"title": "Becoming", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Becoming-Michelle-Obama/dp/1524763136", "price": "$24.72"},
{"title": "Starry Messenger: Cosmic Perspectives on Civilization", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Starry-Messenger-Cosmic-Perspectives-Civilization/dp/1250861500", "price": "$18.04"},
{"title": "Cinema Speculation", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Cinema-Speculation-Quentin-Tarantino/dp/0063112582", "price": "$21.86"},
{"title": "The Song of Achilles: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Song-Achilles-Novel-Madeline-Miller/dp/0062060627", "price": "$10.34"},
{"title": "Going Rogue: Rise and Shine Twenty-Nine (29) (Stephanie Plum)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Going-Rogue-Shine-Twenty-Nine-Stephanie/dp/1668003058", "price": "$15.14"},
{"title": "Confess: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Confess-Novel-Colleen-Hoover-ebook/dp/B00LD1OHE0", "price": "$10.99"},
{"title": "Killing the Legends: The Lethal Danger of Celebrity", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Killing-Legends-Lethal-Danger-Celebrity/dp/1250283302", "price": "$15.00"},
{"title": "Maybe Someday", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Maybe-Someday-Colleen-Hoover-ebook/dp/B00DPM7RJW", "price": "$10.99"},
{"title": "No Plan B: A Jack Reacher Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/No-Plan-Jack-Reacher-Novel/dp/1984818546", "price": "$17.49"},
{"title": "Babel: Or the Necessity of Violence: An Arcane History of the Oxford Translators' Revolution", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Babel-Necessity-Violence-Translators-Revolution/dp/0063021420", "price": "$20.49"},
{"title": "Tomorrow, and Tomorrow, and Tomorrow: A novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Tomorrow-novel-Gabrielle-Zevin/dp/0593321200", "price": "$14.69"},
{"title": "The Midnight Library: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Midnight-Library-Novel-Matt-Haig/dp/0525559477", "price": "$13.59"},
{"title": "A World of Curiosities: A Novel (Chief Inspector Gamache Novel, 18)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/World-Curiosities-Novel-Inspector-Gamache/dp/1250145295", "price": "$20.22"},
{"title": "Tom Clancy Red Winter (A Jack Ryan Novel)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Clancy-Winter-Jack-Ryan-Novel/dp/0593422759", "price": "$20.06"},
{"title": "All About Me!: My Remarkable Life in Show Business", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/All-About-Me-Remarkable-Business/dp/059315911X", "price": "$20.00"},
{"title": "Braiding Sweetgrass: Indigenous Wisdom, Scientific Knowledge and the Teachings of Plants", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Braiding-Sweetgrass-Indigenous-Scientific-Knowledge/dp/1571313567", "price": "$13.25"},
{"title": "What If? 2: Additional Serious Scientific Answers to Absurd Hypothetical Questions", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/What-Additional-Scientific-Hypothetical-Questions/dp/0525537112", "price": "$18.57"},
{"title": "The Song of the Cell: An Exploration of Medicine and the New Human", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Song-Cell-Exploration-Medicine-Human/dp/1982117354", "price": "$16.25"},
{"title": "So Help Me God", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/So-Help-God-Mike-Pence/dp/1982190337", "price": "$21.78"},
{"title": "Radio's Greatest of All Time", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Radios-Greatest-Time-Rush-Limbaugh/dp/1668001845", "price": "$21.49"},
{"title": "The Philosophy of Modern Song", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Philosophy-Modern-Song-Bob-Dylan/dp/1451648707", "price": "$22.50"},
{"title": "An Immense World: How Animal Senses Reveal the Hidden Realms Around Us", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Immense-World-Animal-Senses-Reveal/dp/0593133234", "price": "$18.31"},
{"title": "The Revolutionary: Samuel Adams", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Revolutionary-Samuel-Adams-Stacy-Schiff/dp/0316441112", "price": "$17.50"},
{"title": "And There Was Light: Abraham Lincoln and the American Struggle", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/There-Was-Light-American-Struggle/dp/0553393960", "price": "$20.00"},
{"title": "Lessons in Chemistry: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Lessons-Chemistry-Novel-Bonnie-Garmus/dp/038554734X", "price": "$17.83"},
{"title": "The Body Keeps the Score: Brain, Mind, and Body in the Healing of Trauma", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Body-Keeps-Score-Healing-Trauma/dp/0670785938", "price": "$19.39"},
{"title": "Surrender: 40 Songs, One Story", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Surrender-40-Songs-One-Story/dp/0525521046", "price": "$17.00"},
{"title": "It Starts with Us: A Novel (It Ends with Us)", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Starts-Us-Novel-Ends/dp/1668001225", "price": "$10.98"},
{"title": "It Ends with Us: A Novel", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Ends-Us-Novel-Colleen-Hoover-ebook/dp/B0176M3U10", "price": "$10.99"}
]
```

Comment: This is statics which I can't add into my answer due to over characters limit
{'downloader/request_bytes': 188578,
 'downloader/request_count': 546,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 546,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 25957883,
 'downloader/response_count': 546,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 150,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 192,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/503': 203,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 55,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 55.420902,

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried to use this command to save the result in a Json file but i could find anything, << scrapy crawl ny-times -o ny-times.json           sorry please , I am start studying Scrap but it seems to be a little bit confused to me the json at first time. Thanks for your help again

Comment: @RaoufYahiaoui, -O  (Capital , not small o), can you try it? If still error, let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I did a mistake that's why the program did not run properly, But now I figured out the issue and I reesolved. The program UP and RUN. Now I can unhance it  and do more stuff with it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Bench Vue; I would like to ask you something. Actually I have parsed the output json into an Sql database. But, I found some difficulties to parse it into ElasticSearch. Actually I have created a Function in the Pipeline.py  and I have also added some lines in the settings.py, but even though I cannot even found the index  i have created in elasticSearch. I hope you have an idea about elastic search. I will try to show you the code in another comment. Thanks in advance

Comment: def ingestForES(title: str,rank: int,description):
        es_url = es(hosts=[{'host':'http://x.x.x.x','port': 9200}])
        es = es(es_url,basic_auth=("elastic", "datascientest"), verify_certs=False)
        data = {'title': title,
                'rank':rank,
                'description': description,
                } 
        resp = es.create.index(index='myindex', body=data)
        print(resp)

Comment: and for the lines in settings.y:    ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'amazon.pipelines.AmazonPipeline': 300,
    'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline': 500
}


#ELASTICSEARCH_SERVERS = [{'x.x.x.x': 9200}]
ELASTICSEARCH_SERVERS = 'http://x.x.x.x:9200'
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = 'myindex'
ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE = 'items'

Comment: @RaoufYahiaoui, I have no experience for elastic search, Can you make new questions to ask to everyone?

Comment: Thank you for your reply anyway. Actually I did posted a question but nobody answer me back. I should try it myself using different methods and I hope I find a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you point your question,? I try to learn it. But it will take a time.

Comment: Ok, hope you find a solution. thanks in advance. One thing to note: the first two functions inside the class are used to parse the data into sqllite and the third one is the elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a Question:
My question is about How to parse a data to ElasticSearch after being scrapped:
This is my code but it misses something:
In pipelines.py

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
import sqlite3
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch as es
class AmazonPipeline:
"""
def __init__(self):

    self.con = sqlite3.connect('books.db')
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()
    self.cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book_prices(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        title TEXT,
        price INTEGER,
        ratings INTEGER,
        url TEXT
    )
    """)

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    ## Define insert statement
    self.cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO book_prices (title, price, ratings, url) VALUES (?, ?, 
?, ?)
    """,
    (
        item['title'],
        item['price'],
        item['ratings'],
        item['url']
    ))

    ## Execute insert of data into database
    self.con.commit()
    return item
"""
#This is the code that should connect and create an index in Elasticsearch

def ingestForES(title: str,rank: int,description):
    es_url = es(hosts=[{'host':'http://34.255.105.149','port': 9200}])
    es = es(es_url,basic_auth=("elastic", "datascientest"), 
verify_certs=False)
    data = {'title': title,
            'rank':rank,
            'description': description,
            } 
    resp = es.create.index(index='myindex', body=data)
    print(resp)
```

and in the settings.py I added the following lines:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'amazon.pipelines.AmazonPipeline': 300,
'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline': 500
}


ELASTICSEARCH_SERVERS = 'http://34.255.105.149:9200'
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX = 'myindex'
ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE = 'items'
#ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY = 'url'
```